# How to add IP restrictions to my amazon ec2 instance installed with ubuntu 12

Tags: ubuntu, ip-address, amazon-ec2

I have to add IP restrictions to my amazon EC2 instance , The reason for doing it is , I dont want to allow to do ssh from all places , it should be allowed only from my ip address. I am new to amazon , Please kindly provide some instructions regarding this

Thanks in advance for responding to this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you read this article: [Tips for Securing Your EC2 Instance](https://aws.amazon.com/articles/1233)? I believe it has the information you need.

You should authorise your IP address (e.g. assuming your IP address is 1.2.3.4):

```
PROMPT> ec2-authorize default -p 22 -s 1.2.3.4
```

And then simply create SSH key pairs for all your users and authorise the public key of the pairs with the `ec2-add-keypair` command as described in the *Ditch Those Passwords: Use ssh Keys* of the above mentioned article. This way only the users with authorised SSH key pairs from the authorised IP will be able to connect.

Comment: Yup I had read that , But I have several users created and I want all of them to use the same my office ip address to do ssh , how I can do that

Comment: @aravind.udayashankara: added more details for possible solution.